# Finding a float in a python list

Tags: python

I am surprised to see this python behavior, but couldn't understand why? I am not able to search 0.3 in a python list.

```
>> import numpy as np
>> Lambdas = np.arange(0.0, 1.05, 0.05)
>> print(Lambdas)
[0.   0.05 0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3  0.35 0.4  0.45 0.5  0.55 0.6  0.65
 0.7  0.75 0.8  0.85 0.9  0.95 1.  ]
>> print(0.3 in Lambdas)
False
>> print(0.30 in Lambdas)
False
>> print(0.1 in Lambdas)
True
>> print(0.4 in Lambdas)
True
>> print(1 in Lambdas)
True
>> print(1.0 in Lambdas)
True
>> print(0.1 in Lambdas)
True
>>
```

Comment: Because the value in the `Lambdas` is not exactly `0.3`, but instead something like `0.300000000004`, it's just how floating point numbers work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://0.30000000000000004.com/

> Your language isn't broken, it's doing floating point math. Computers can only natively store integers, so they need some way of
>   representing decimal numbers. This representation comes with some
>   degree of inaccuracy. That's why, more often than not, .1 + .2 != .3.
>
> Why does this happen? It's actually pretty simple. When you have a
>   base 10 system (like ours), it can only express fractions that use a
>   prime factor of the base. The prime factors of 10 are 2 and 5. So 1/2,
>   1/4, 1/5, 1/8, and 1/10 can all be expressed cleanly because the
>   denominators all use prime factors of 10. In contrast, 1/3, 1/6, and
>   1/7 are all repeating decimals because their denominators use a prime
>   factor of 3 or 7. In binary (or base 2), the only prime factor is 2.
>   So you can only express fractions cleanly which only contain 2 as a
>   prime factor. In binary, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 would all be expressed cleanly
>   as decimals. While, 1/5 or 1/10 would be repeating decimals. So 0.1
>   and 0.2 (1/10 and 1/5) while clean decimals in a base 10 system, are
>   repeating decimals in the base 2 system the computer is operating in.
>   When you do math on these repeating decimals, you end up with
>   leftovers which carry over when you convert the computer's base 2
>   (binary) number into a more human readable base 10 number.

Answer (score 1):

As per Mehdi's comprehensive answer and ruohola's comment, the floating point value stored in the array is likely not to be exactly 0.3

You can try using `numpy.allclose()`, setting the tolerance for the minimum difference with the `atol` or `rtol` arguments - docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)

Comment: yes, got it. Thanks.